# Why is the photo printer Canon SELPHY CP800 unable to display and print JPG photos edited in GIMP?

Tags: printer

I edited photos in Gimp, exported them as JPEG and tried to print them using the compact photo printer Canon SELPHY CP800.

The photos I edited in Gimp are (other than e.g. photos from my camera) not displayed on the printer and I'm unable to print them.
Instead of the photo, the photo printer just shows a yellow/orange question mark.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are the photos saved in JPG format? Gimp’s native file format is XCF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When exporting the photo as JPG open the "advanced settings" in the export dialogue windows.
**Untick** the "progressive" check box.

This solved the problem for me.

Here's a (german) screenshot:

[image: photo export dialogue for JPEG]

Comment: Did that do it? I'm guessing it did. It might be worth adding some explanation of what that box does (for example https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/what-is-a-progressive-jpeg/).

Comment: nope!
You have to have in JPG not .JPEG though - sorted that part but stil wont read some scanned picture